# Notification when an answer to your question is edited

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, editing, answers, notifications

I've noticed that as the question author you get notifications if there is a new answer, but not if an existing answer is edited. That doesn't seem right, as often edits are worth seeing, and as the one who wrote the question, you would probably be interested in keeping abreast of the new information.

Comment: I can't imagine this didn't come up before, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree that such notifications are important -- and *especially* if an *accepted* answer is edited, because by accepting you've endorsed it and you should know if what you've endorsed has changed.